# Restriction of irreducible integrable connections

Tags: fundamental-group, d-modules, local-systems

Let $X$ be a complex analytic manifold and let $\mathcal{M}$ be an integrable connection on $X$, i.e. a $\mathcal{D}_X$-module which happens to be coherent as an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. If $U$ is any open subset of $X$ then $\mathcal{M}_{|U}$ is an integrable connection on $U$.

Suppose that $\mathcal{M}$ is irreducible and $U$ is connected. Must $\mathcal{M}_{|U}$ also be irreducible?

Comment: What if $\mathcal{M}$ comes from an irreducible representation of the fundamental group of $X$, yet $U$ is simply connected (a polydisk, say)?